# File transfer to a remote machine in amazon ec2

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, file-transfer

after creating a instance in amazon cloud using webservice in java i need to transfer a executable file or war file via program from my local machine to the newly created instance in amazon and i want to execute that excetuable,i tried and found that there is something called createbucket in ec2 api and using that we can upload the file to that and we can transfer that reference using PutObjectRequest i can transfer the reference to a remote computer in amazon do it is possible or if it is wrong please suggest me the correct way to proceed for file transfer from my local machine to the amazon ec2.

Answer (score 0):

The basic suggestion is, you shouldn't transfer the file(s) with CreateBucket, which is actually an S3 API. Use scp may be a better solution.

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), which you are trying to use with CreateBucket, is a data storage service mainly for flexible, public (with authentication) file sharing. You can use REST or SOAP APIs to access the data, but cannot really read/write it in EC2 instances as if it's in local harddisk.

To access file system in EC2 instances, that really depends on your operating system (on EC2). If it's running Linux, [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) is a mature choice. You can use Java to directly invoke `scp`, if you are using Linux locally, or [pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) if you are using Windows. If the EC2 instance is running Windows, one choice is to host an SSH/SFTP environment with [FreeSSHD](http://www.freesshd.com/), and then proceed like Linux. Another option is use Shared Folder and regular file copy.

Comment: Uploading to S3 is a pain in the ass.. I would not recommend that to anyone.